# Need help on mysql date range query

Tags: mysql, sql

Below query I am using in my search

I have date range in search, when I searching data between '01/05/2012' AND '31/05/2012' date range but query return all record set.

```
SELECT t.created date, t.saleid sale_id, u.id user_id, NULL merchant_name, cheque_number cheque_number, u.first_name name, (
SELECT company_name
FROM users
WHERE id = u.my_charity_id)charity_name, t.campaignname website, t.campaignid campaign_id, t.mysoko_discount discount_percentage, t.discount, t.salecommission sale_commission, t.salevalue total_sale_value, t.salestatus sale_status
FROM `transaction` AS `t` , `users` AS `u`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( t.created, '%d/%m/%Y' )
BETWEEN '01/05/2012' AND '31/05/2012'
AND t.user_id = u.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I am looking for date range search data but result return all data from table.

```
date            sale_id       user_id   
2012-04-19 00:00:00     20253305    45  
2012-04-11 00:00:00     20253306    68  
2012-04-23 00:00:00     20253307    68  
2012-04-25 00:00:00     20253308    45  
2012-04-27 00:00:00     20253309    45  
2012-04-29 00:00:00     20253310    68  
2012-04-30 00:00:00     20253311    45  
2012-05-01 00:00:00     20253312    45  
2012-05-03 00:00:00     20253313    68  
2012-04-18 00:00:00     20253314    4
```

My search is from date range  txn search (from / to date)

INPUT date format: DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
WHERE t.created BETWEEN '2012-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-31 23:59:59' ...
```

MySQL will interpret '2012-05-31 23:59:59' as the appropriate DATETIME or TIMESTAMP type, allowing you to take advantage of an index on `t.created`.

Your problem is that your current query specifies that the *string representation* of `t.created` be between the *strings* '01/05/2012' and '31/05/2012'.  Since you string format day-month-year, any date whose day component is between '02' and '30', inclusive, will match.  (And the first of any month of May or later will match, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try filtering rows like this:

```
WHERE t.created >= '2012-05-01'
  AND t.created <  '2012-06-01'
```

If the month is specified as an argument, you could use the following calculations in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE t.created >= @monthdate
  AND t.created <  @monthdate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
 WHERE MONTH(t.created) = 5 AND YEAR(t.created) = 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.created date, t.saleid sale_id, u.id user_id, NULL merchant_name, cheque_number cheque_number, u.first_name name, (
SELECT company_name
FROM users
WHERE id = u.my_charity_id)charity_name, t.campaignname website, t.campaignid campaign_id, t.mysoko_discount discount_percentage, t.discount, t.salecommission sale_commission, t.salevalue total_sale_value, t.salestatus sale_status
FROM `transaction` AS `t` , `users` AS `u`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( t.created, '%d/%m/%Y' )
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2012','%d,%m,%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31/05/2012','%d,%m,%Y')
AND t.user_id = u.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: you will have to be sure that t.created is of date format as well

Comment: Sebas I am getting empty result MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0418 sec )